# How should the "drupal.org" tag be renamed?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I have seen some users using [drupal.org](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drupal.org) for questions that are not about drupal.org; probably they pick up that tag because it contains the word "drupal." This reminds me of when on drupal.org users select "drupal.org module" as issue component, when that component is referring to the [Drupal.org customizations](http://drupal.org/project/drupalorg) module.

Is it possible to use a different name for the tag, to avoid it gets misused?

#### **Update**

I removed the tag from other 7 questions. The questions from which I removed the tag where questions about modules, or code to write for modules. The tag is not going to be picked up because it's not clear what its purpose is, as the tag has an excerpt.

[image: screenshot]

I think that the tag is being picked up because the users start writing "drupal," they get a suggestion for that tag, see it doesn't contains specific words (which would happen with [drupal-commerce](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drupal-commerce)), and decide the tag is right because Drupal.org is the official Drupal site, where the Drupal development is planned.

It would probably help if "drupal" would not be the first part of the tag, and if the tag would contain another word, such as in [community-drupal-org](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-drupal-org).

Comment: how many of the *current* questions in that tag are mis-tagged?

Comment: 10/3.5k questions is tagged with drupal.org. If only part of them is tagged wrong, That's hardly a problem. Let's not make problems out of nothing.

Comment: @googletorp Did you count the questions from which I removed the tag? I don't think you can possibly count them.

Comment: As a matter of fact, the tag was wrongly added in (for example) [Drupal 7 Front end slider](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6749/drupal-7-front-end-slider) and [Reason for javascript disabled in drupal site?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5482/reason-for-javascript-disabled-in-drupal-site) where the question was not about drupal.org or the Drupal.org community. Out of the 10 questions that @Jeff is referring to, only 4 should have used it.

Comment: @kiam My point was that it is used so rarely that it's not to be considdered a gerenal problem. It is not important If there were 10 or 20 questions tagged like this. It's still a too small fraction to indicate random use.

Comment: @googletorp Supposing that I have removed the tag from 5 questions before to remove it from the 10 questions reported by Jeff (I didn't count them but for sure they were at least 5 questions), it means the tag has been used in 15 questions, and in 11 cases the tag should not have been used; it means 73.3% of the questions that used that tag used it wrongly. If you count the number of questions in a SE site, then nobody would even create a tag synonym on Stack Overflow, because it's hard that the questions using a wrong tag would be a significant percentage of the total number of questions.

Comment: 15 questions out of 3500 is 0.4%. Not some worth discussing bit should just be changed in silence.

Comment: @googletorp See my previous comment. I then fail to see how it can be changed in silence, though, as there isn't a "rename tag" link; even if there would be, I don't know how I should communicate that the tag should be changed to who can change it, and how somebody can propose what the better name to use is, if nobody sees a question asked on this very site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I renamed it [community-drupal-org](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-drupal-org).
Since it has been renamed, it was not picked up by mistake anymore.